# Unable to import string in python 3

Tags: python

```
import random
import string
def pw_gen(size = 8, chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))

print(pw_gen(int(input('How many characters in your password'))))
```

I am trying to run this code but when importing `string`, I am receiving this error:

```
There are 10 types of people.
Those who know binary and those who don't.
I said: %r.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "passgen1.py", line 3, in <module>
    import string
  File "D:\python\string.py", line 9, in <module>
    print ("I said: %r.") % x
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

Comment: Is your script called string.py?

Comment: Are you actually trying to import the built-in `string` or your own file string? If it is the built-in, you need to change you file name from string because it is shadowing the built-in one. And anyway, it seems that you have a problem with that file...

Comment: it would work in Python 2 which would treat `print ("I said: %r.") % x` as `print "I said: %r." % x`. But in Python 3 it is incorrect and you have to do it inside `()` - `print(  "I said: %r." % x )` or generate text before printing - `text =  "I said: %r." % x` and later `print(text)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `string.py` module there appears to be this code:

> ```
> print ("I said: %r.") % x
> ```

Which is evaluated like this:

1. `print("I said: %r.")` is executed, which results in the value `None` (because `print` doesn't return anything).
2. This value (which is `None`) is inserted in the above expression, so `None % x` is evaluated. This results in the error message you see.

It seems you meant to write:

```
print("I said: %r." % x)
```

i.e., first insert `x` in the string, *then* print it.